SAS Proc Report variable columns
I am trying to automate a daily report using Proc Report (instead of Excel). The report is a running 8-day report with the dates being the column names. How do I reference the date columns in the COLUMN and DEFINE statements, so that I can format the cell values?
I used TRANSPOSE to get 1 record per BY group.
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=WORK.DAILYRPT OUT=WORK.DAILYRPT_TRANSPOSE(DROP=_NAME_);
    ID MetricDT; /* e.g. 09/02/2024 */
    IDLABEL DOW; /* e.g. Mon 09/02 */
    VAR MetricValueDaily;
    BY BusinessUnitOrderSEQ BusinessUnitNM GroupOrderSEQ MetricGrp LabelOrderSEQ MetricLBL;
RUN;

The dates change every day, so the report run on 9/8 would show 8/31-9/7, and the report run on 9/9 would be from 9/1-9/8. (Report is not run on the weekends)
When I run PROC REPORT w/o any statements, I get this:
Proc report

Dates are not normally valid variable names.  Did you accidentally create the dataset while running with VALIDVARNAME option set to ANY ?

What is the REPORT you want to create? Why do you think you need to first transpose the data to have PROC REPORT use the values of METRICDT as the column headers?  Why not just make METRICDT and ACROSS variable in the REPORT?

What kind of formatting do you want? Traffic highlighting based on metric?

I'm trying to format the numbers in the cells (Comma10.0). This report is seen by upper management. Someone with more experience than me with Proc Report had suggested transposing the dates. I'll try making MetricDT the across variable. The variable names are actually the DOW values (day of week + MM/DD)
